# Does a foreign need to be mandatory and whats a better way of doing this?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Im creating a online video game database and I have two tables where a foreign key could be null. It is the users and teams table, the team table relates to the user tables as '1 to many' but the user may not be in a team therefore making the foreign key not mandatory, is there a better way of doing this as I feel like having a null foreign key is bad practice

Comment: Can one user belong to multiple teams?

Comment: For the test data im using no, otherwise I would of created a 'linking table' to stop the many to many relationship

Comment: You don't need to place foreign key from users to teams table as user may or may not exist in teams table. Other way round is fine i.e. if team has a user, he must exist in users table.

Comment: Sorry but I dont follow with what you are saying, Are you saying I can put the foreign key (users_id) inside the team table rather than putting team_id inside the users table which was my original problem?

Comment: Yes, teams table will be referencing user_id from users table as foreign key and not the other way round.

Comment: Ok thank you, would this still be a 1 to many relationship from team to users table though?

Comment: Yes, foreign key doesn't constrain cardinality, it only ensures valid data is present first in the parent table before being used in the child table.

Comment: Surely the answer is a mapping table called UserTeam or similar that contains FK to User and FK to Team, eg User <-> UserTeam <-> Team

Comment: A nullable foreign key is not bad practice, if it accurately represents the relationship between the entities.

Answer (score 0):

If you refuse to use a nullable field as a foreign key -- personally I don't have a problem with this -- then about your only option would be a junction table.  You can prevent that table from creating a many-to-many relationship by making the the user id unique.  That will force it to a many-to-one.

```
CREATE TABLE UserTeam (
    UserID INT NOT NULL,
    TeamID INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_UserTeam PRIMARY KEY (UserID),
    CONSTRAINT U_UserTeam_UserID UNIQUE (UserID, TeamID),
    CONSTRAINT FK_UserTeam_UserID FOREIGN KEY (UserID)
        REFERENCES dbo.User (UserID),
    CONSTRAINT FK_UserTeam_TeamID FOREIGN KEY (TeamID)
        REFERENCES dbo.Team (TeamID)
)
```

The issue here is that you've got a one-to-one relationship between `UserTeam` and `User` and you're only doing it for one field.  It can be easy enough to imagine other fields (a start date, a position, etc.) but it's a bit odd to make a whole table for one field just because you don't like nulls.

Comment: Why do you say that "The issue here is that you've got a one-to-one relationship between UserTeam and User"? In your solution it is 1 (user side) to many (team side).

Comment: @NoChance Because the standard one-to-one relationship is a single table.  Each column in a table is already one-to-one with the primary key of the table.  That's what a table is. So you need to consider carefully why you're adding a new table that's going to be one-to-one instead of just adding a column to the existing table.  "Nulls are bad" is philosophically correct, but it's often more practical and scalable to just allow nulls.  You'll still have to deal with null values anyways when you do your joins.

Comment: I guess the word 'here' has introduced some confusion. You are probably referring to the OP's current solution and not to your solution. Anyway, it is a minor thing, I would suggest not to include that sentence, but it is up to you.